# Selecting data on median value

Tags: python, numpy, selection, precision, analysis

I want to select one row of an array by the median value in one of the columns.

My method does not work the way I expect it to work, and it could be related to the representation/precision of the value returned by the numpy.median() function.

Here is a minimal working example and a workaround that I found:

```
import numpy as np

# Create an array with random numbers
some_array = np.random.rand(100)

# Try to select
selection = (some_array == np.median(some_array))
print len(some_array[selection]),len(some_array[~selection]) # Gives: 0, 100 -> selection fails

# Work-around
abs_dist_from_median = np.abs(some_array-np.median(some_array))
selection = (abs_dist_from_median == np.min(abs_dist_from_median))
print len(some_array[selection]),len(some_array[~selection]) # Gives: 1, 99 -> selection succeeded
```

It seems that the np.median() function returns a different representation off the number, thereby leading to a mismatch in the selection.

I find this behaviour strange, since by definition the median value of an array should be contained in the array. Any help/clarification would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the number of values is even such as `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. the median is `(2+3)/2` not `2` or `3`. If you change `100` to `101`, it works properly. So your second approach is more appropriate on your purpose.

However, the best solution seems to use `argsort` as

```
some_array[some_array.argsort()[len(some_array)/2]]
```

Also, do not use `==` when you compare two `float` values. use `np.isclose` instead.

Comment: This is concise and aesthetic and will do for most (not big) problems. Determining the median does not require a full `O(n log(n))` sort and can be done in [linear time](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ib/Classes/CS515_Spring12-13/Slides/022-SelectMasterThm.pdf), but this is not implemented in numpy as far as I can see.

Comment: It is implemented in numpy: [`np.argpartition`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html).